# how to get to my physical foldoer?

Tags: asp.net

I am writing an application in asp.net. My current page is in this folder:
D:\VisualStudio2015\Source\VestVB\admin\abc.aspx. 
I want to go to the folder of D:\VisualStudio2015\Source. 
when I write the code: Response.write(Server.MapPath(".")), 
I got: D:VisualStudio2015\Source\VestVB\admin. 
if I change the code to server.mapPath(".."), 
I got D:VisualStudio2015\Source\VestVB. 
if I change the code to server.mapPath("../..")
I got ERROR: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory. 
How can I get to D:VisualStudio2015\Scource?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Server.MapPath` to get the "physical" path name of you Website. Then you can use the normal functionality of the `Path` class to get parent folders:

```
string lWebProjectRoot = Server.MapPath("~");
string lBaseDir = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(lWebProjectRoot, ".."));
```